# .NET/C# - AnonymousPipeServerStream/AnonymousPipeClientStream not working

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I would like to exchange data between AnonymousPipeServerStream and AnonymousPipeClientStream

This code is not working. It is block on Join.

```
Console.WriteLine("> " + text2);
```

is never called

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks

```
 using (AnonymousPipeServerStream pipeout = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out))
            {
                using (AnonymousPipeClientStream pipein = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In,
                    pipeout.GetClientHandleAsString()))
                {

                    byte[] res;
                    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream x = new MemoryStream())
                        {

                            pipein.CopyTo(x);
                            res = x.ToArray();
                            string text2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res);
                            Console.WriteLine("> " + text2);


                        }
                    });
                    t.Start();

                    string text = "hello !";
                    using (MemoryStream x = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)))
                    {
                        x.CopyTo(pipeout);
                    }


                    t.Join();
                }               
            }
```

Comment: Try `pipeout.Close(); t.Join();` although quite why you would ever use such code I don't know

Comment: I need to use an output Stream as input Stream and an input Stream as output Stream

Comment: Thanks, pipeout.Close();  works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the outbound pipe, otherwise the client side will just keep waiting for more data

```cs
pipeout.Close();
t.Join()
```

Alternatively you can close the `using` before waiting on the thread. (you need to move the declaration of `Thread t;` outside the `using`)

```cs
}
t.Join();
```

But I'm not sure why you would want to use such code. For in-process communication it would be wiser to just use some kind of thread-safe queue. Furthermore, you should probably use tasks not threads.

Comment: I can't use queue because I must user Stream (MemoeyStream, FileStream, NetworkStream...)
Thanks